# (Array of objects) The method is undefined for the type

Tags: java, arrays, eclipse

I am using eclipse ide.
I am creating a program to make an array of objects and get input from the user using scanner class.
When I'm trying to set input to the method variable I'm getting error which is:
*The method set_no(Int) is undefined for the type BookDetails*, where **set_no is a method of class Book** and **BookDetails is the main class**. And I'm getting it for all 4 methods.

Here is the code:

This is the Book class:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Book {
    private int bookno;
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private float price;

    public Book(){
        bookno=0;
        title="Anonymous";
        author="Anonymous";
        price=0;
    }
        public void set_no(int no) {
            this.bookno=no;
        }
        public void set_title(String t) {
            if(t.length()<4) {
                System.out.println("Error, the title of the book can't be less than 4 characters\n");
            }
            else {
                this.title=t;
            }
        }
        public void set_author(String a) {
            this.author=a;
        }
        public void set_price(int p) {
            if(p<1 || p>5000) {
                System.out.println("Error, the price is out of range\n");
            }
            else {
                this.price=p;
            }
        }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = "Book number: "+Integer.toString(bookno)+",\n"+"Title: "+title+",\n"+"Author: "+author+",\n"+"Price: Rs. "+Float.toString(price)+".\n";
        return s;
    }
}
```

This is the main class:

```
public class BookDetails{
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        Book[] b=new Book[3];
        for(int i=0; i<b.length; i++) {
            b[i]=new Book();
        }
        for(int i=0; i<b.length; i++) {
            System.out.println("Enter the book number: ");
            b[i]=set_no(sc.nextInt());                      //The method set_no(int) is undefined for the type BookDetails
            System.out.println("Enter the book title: ");
            b[i]=set_title(sc.nextLine());                 //The method set_title(String) is undefined for the type BookDetails
            System.out.println("Enter the name of the author: ");
            b[i]=set_author(sc.nextLine());               //The method set_author(String) is undefined for the type BookDetails
            System.out.println("Enter the price of the book: ");
            b[i]=set_price(sc.nextFloat());               //The method set_price(String) is undefined for the type BookDetails
        }
        for(int i=0; i<b.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(b[i].toString());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Note: read about java naming conventions. Method names go like `setNo()` in java. No "_". And: dont abbreviate. Just call it `setNumber()` .

Comment: You are calling the method `set_no` without qualifying it (e.g. `something.set_no(...)`). Java tries to find the method in the *current class* (i.e. `BookDetails.set_no(...)`). Try `b[i].set_no(...)` instead.

Comment: Also, just like GhostCat says, you should follow the Java Naming Conventions: variabele names and method names should be written in camelCase; class names in PascalCase.

Comment: Furthermore, I recommend to implement a constructor which sets the several fields, instead of having only one no-argument constructor.

Comment: Yeah guys, I've taken the java naming conventions into my consideration and changed the naming according to that. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`set_no` is a method of `Book`, so you need to call it on an instance of `Book`, in this case `b[i]`.

So,  write `b[i].set_no(sc.nextInt())` (and likewise for other methods).

Answer (score 0):

Getters and setters in Java not like TypeScript/JavaScript , you dont need the under line in java (`_`)

I changed your code to getters and setters like Java functions :

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Book {
    private int bookNo;
    private String title;
    private String author;
    private float price;

    public Book(){
        bookNo=0;
        title="Anonymous";
        author="Anonymous";
        price=0;
    }
        public void setBookNo(int newBookNo) {
            this.bookno=newBookNo;
        }
        public void setTitle(String newTitle) {
            if(newTitle.length()<4) {
                System.out.println("Error, the title of the book can't be less than 4 characters\n");
            }
            else {
                this.title=newTitle;
            }
        }
        public void setAuthor(String newAuthor) {
            this.author=newAuthor;
        }
        public void setPrice(int newPrice) {
            if(newPrice<1 || newPrice>5000) {
                System.out.println("Error, the price is out of range\n");
            }
            else {
                this.price=newPrice;
            }
        }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        String s = "Book number: "+Integer.toString(bookNo)+",\n"+"Title: "+title+",\n"+"Author: "+author+",\n"+"Price: Rs. "+Float.toString(price)+".\n";
        return s;
    }
}
```